# How can I add Eclipse IDE to the applications menu and dock?

Tags: plank, slingshot, eclipse

I have installed the Eclipse IDE and I can't find its icon in application menu. How can I bring it to application menu and dock?

Comment: How did you install it? Via Software-Center or did you download it from their website and installed in manually?

Comment: I have downloaded from officially site. And started with sudo permission in terminal.

Comment: See [this thread](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/17083/elementaryos-juno-after-eclipse-ide-install-impossible-to-add-icon-after-linked/17089#17089) for a GUI solution to the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a .desktop file and save it under
`~/.local/share/applications/eclipse.desktop`

See [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80013/how-to-pin-eclipse-to-the-unity-launcher) for more information.