# ElementaryOS Juno after Eclipse IDE install impossible to add icon after linked in Application menu and Plank

Tags: release-juno, icons

I can't get the icon for Eclipse to display, although the exec link is present in the Applications menu and Plank, after checking instructions [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/4241/how-can-i-add-eclipse-ide-to-the-applications-menu-and-dock) but it won't display the icon.

I have created an "EclipseIDE.desktop" file using nano in /home/user/.local/applications/

Contents as follows:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Type=Application
Name=EclipseIDE
Comment=Eclipse Integrated Development Environment
Icon=/usr/share/pixmaps/eclipse.xpm
Exec=/opt/eclipse/eclipse
Terminal=false
Categories=Development;IDE;Java;
StartupWMClass=Eclipse
```

I have eclipse's icon copied in both locations cp /opt/eclipse/icon.xpm /usr/share/pixmaps/eclipse.xpm
but the icon won't display either in Applications menu or Plank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about `Eclipse` but I recommend to install `AppEditor` from `AppCentre`

Is a simple tool to edit/create menu shortcuts

[image: appeditor main window]

https://appcenter.elementary.io/com.github.donadigo.appeditor/

---

Anyway I just installed Eclipse via `snap` and the icon is OK, for that kind of app I recommend have the latest and snap (in this case) is the easiest and best way to get it

https://snapcraft.io/eclipse

Comment: AppEditor elegantly solves the problem using a GUI. As I have Eclipse already installed, it's the best working solution! Thank you!

Comment: Well looks like wasn't that helpful after all, my solution was accepted and now (1 hour ago) marked as unaccepted (- rep) ... with this kind of bs (sorrry my french) I don't feel the need to keep answering anymore

Comment: Manipulation error, sorry, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to the eclipse.desktop file, here's how it has been edited by AppEditor:

[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Type=Application
Name=EclipseIDE
Comment=Eclipse Integrated Development Environment
Icon=/opt/eclipse/icon.xpm
Exec=/opt/eclipse/eclipse
Terminal=false
Categories=IDE;Java;Development;
StartupWMClass=Eclipse
Name[en_IL]=EclipseIDE
X-GNOME-FullName[en_IL]=EclipseIDE
Comment[en_IL]=Eclipse Integrated Development Environment 
NoDisplay=false
Path=
X-GNOME-UsesNotifications=false

All in one text block without interline space; Icon= / Exec= have to be edited with your path for the icon and the exec file that starts Eclipse, respectively.
Normally these are located in /opt/eclipse/